# Select author of opinion

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, view

There is a file: **Opinion.cshtml** in Views/Home.

```
@model Aquapark.ViewModels.OpinionViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Opinia";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_StoreLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Opinia</h2>
<div style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: 22px;">
    <div class="opinion-box">
        @foreach (var opinions in Model.Opinions)
        {
            <div class="opinion-box-content">
                <div class="opinion-box-content-inside">@opinions.Content</div>
                <div class="date">@opinions.Date</div>
            </div>
            <div class="opinion-author">@opinions.PersonId</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I have file: **OpinionViewModel.cs** in a **ViewModel** folder(created).

```
using Aquapark.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Aquapark.ViewModels
{
    public class OpinionViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Opinion> Opinions { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Person> Authors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Person.cs**

```
namespace Aquapark.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("Person")]
    public partial class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long Pesel { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Imię nie może zawierać więcej niż 30 znaków.")]
        [Display(Name = "Imię")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Nazwisko nie może zawierać wiecej niż 60 znaków.")]
        [Display(Name = "Nazwisko")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Data urodzenia")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth  { get; set; }

        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private AquaparkContext db = new AquaparkContext();
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var opinions = db.Opinion.ToList();
            //var randomOpinions = db.Opinion.Where(a => a.Date >= DateTime.Parse("2015-01-01")).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(6).ToList();
            var authors = from p in db.Person
                          join o in db.Opinion
                          on p.PersonId equals o.PersonId
                          select new
                          {
                              p.FullName
                          };

            var vm = new OpinionViewModel()
            {
                Opinions = opinions,
                //Authors = authors,
            };
            return View(vm);
        }

        public ActionResult StaticContent(string viewname)
        {
            return View(viewname);
        }
```

Problem:
I want to display the author(FirstName and LastName) of the opinion. I tried to use LINQ to select data(HomeController var authors), but I can't attribute to collection Authors, because there is a error.

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  C:\Users\Asus
>   N551\OneDrive\Documents\Aquapark\Aquapark\Controllers\HomeController.cs   31  27  Aquapark

How correctly resolve issue?

Comment: You have two issues: you're not using `ToList()` or other suitable for the `authors` and you're also only selecting `p.FullName` and expecting to get types of `Person` out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write code  `select new` you create a new anonymous type.since it is an anonymous type it does not know which value to match up.Whereas if you add `.ToList()` this assumes that your class is `Ienumerable` which should match up what you are trying to return.

Other than calling `.ToList()` you can also do something like this.

```
   IEnumerable<Person> authors = (from p in db.Person
                      join o in db.Opinion
                      on p.PersonId equals o.PersonId
                      select new Person
                      {
                          FullName=p.FirstName+p.LastName
                      }).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var opinions = db.Opinions
.Select(x => new 
{
    x.Id,
    AuthorFullName = x.Author.FirstName + " " + x.Author.LastName,
    Body = x.Body
})
.ToList();
```